# Firebase.once not running callback when page isn't first loaded

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have a view on my Ionic app that simply displays a select dropdown menu, and then prompts the user to type in a number. The number is then saved to that specific user's object in the miles object, the key being the selected option and the value being the number typed in. Here is the code for the controller and view.

Controller:

```
// Get who is logged in
$scope.user = facebook.get();
// Array of airlines
var airRef = ref.child("airlines");
$scope.airlines = $firebaseArray(airRef);
console.log($scope.airlines);
$scope.selectedAir = {};
$scope.miles = {};
// Add program to user
$scope.addProgram = function () {
  if(jQuery.isEmptyObject($scope.user)) {
      var authData = ref.getAuth();
      var theUser = ref.child("users").child(authData.uid);
      var selected = {};

      theUser.child("miles").child($scope.selectedAir.name.$id).once("value", function(snapshot) {
          console.log("apples");

          var exist = snapshot.exists();
          if(!exist) {
              selected[$scope.selectedAir.name.$id] = $scope.miles.num;
              theUser.child("miles").update(selected);
              $state.go("app.saved");
          } else {
              var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Oops!',
                template: "You already created this airline! Go to the 'Add Ticket' page to add more points."
              });
              alertPopup.then(function(res) {
                console.log("You already created this airline! Go to the 'Add Ticket' page to add more points.");
              });
          }
      })

  } else {
      var theUser = ref.child("users").child($scope.user.id);
      var selected = {};

      theUser.child("miles").child($scope.selectedAir.name.$id).once("value", function(snapshot) {
          var exist = snapshot.exists();
          if(!exist) {
              selected[$scope.selectedAir.name.$id] = $scope.miles.num;
              theUser.child("miles").update(selected);
              $state.go("app.saved");
          } else {
              var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Oops!',
                template: "You already created this airline! Go to the 'Add Ticket' page to add more points."
              });
              alertPopup.then(function(res) {
                console.log("You already created this airline! Go to the 'Add Ticket' page to add more points.");
              });
          }
      })

  }
}
```

View:

```
<ion-view view-title="Add a Program">
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item" ng-click="goBack()">
  <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i>
</button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list marginZeroA paddingTL width80">
          <p class="mainText"> </p>
          <div class="list">
              <label class="item item-input item-select">
                  <div class="input-label">

                  </div>
                  <select ng-model="selectedAir.name" ng-options="airline.$id for airline in airlines">

                </select>
            </label>
          </div>
          <label class="item item-input loginInputs">
              <input style="color:black"ng-model="miles.num" class="milesPoints" type="number" min="0" max="10000000"
                placeholder="30000" ng-click="revealInput(1)">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-outline button-calm loginButton
            saveTicket" ng-click="addProgram()" disabled> Add </button>
    </div>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

---

The app works perfect when I load into that specific view, but if I start from the login page as would normally be done it will not work.
If I provide the wrong child id here:

```
.child($scope.selectedAir.name.$id).once("value",
```

I will get a console error telling me its wrong so I know it is trying to run, but when a correct child id is passed in nothing happens. No callback, no error catching. Thanks

Comment: When you change state, just refresh this controller.You can refresh state using 
`$state.go('login', {}, {reload: true})
$state.transitionTo('login', {}, {reload: true});`

Comment: This is the problem you're facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483324/how-can-i-get-a-controller-to-refresh-in-angularjs

Comment: So this part works when I do that:
     `$scope.airlines = $firebaseArray(airRef);`
But this still does not:
     `theUser.child("miles").child($scope.selectedAir.name.$id).once("value", function(snapshot) {`

Comment: I have tested this inside Chrome Developer tools and the JS hits the `.once` function and then skips right to the ending `}` without ever throwing an error or performing any of the inside commands.

Comment: I solved it. I discovered that the callback would not run only if I had visited my home view. A the end of my Firebase functions there I had called `Firebase.goOffline()` to help save on concurrent connections. Once I declared `Firebase.goOnline()` before I a ran my function inside the AddProgram view it worked. Firebase should look into some sort of error message for that, thanks for the help Hardik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my issue:

When a Firebase function such as `ref.once('value', ... )` or `ref.update( ... )` does not perform any of the inside commands as well as does not throw an error, which is caught in the error callback, then most likely your application is not connected to Firebase because of a `Firebase.goOffline()` call. This was in my case and I called this inside another view and when I switched views `Firebase.goOnline()` was never called to turn the connection back on.